# Scala convention for Future type if result doesn't matter

Tags: scala

I have a future for which I care if it completes successfully, but the result is meaningless. One such example is a Future that saves or deletes a record from a DB. 
What is the best way to represent such future? Future[Any]? Future[Unit]?

Answer (score 0):

Future[Unit] is the normal way. It shows a bit more intent than Future[Any]. ie. You know that there is nothing within the future that you care about.

Comment: Thanks! What's the canonical way of mapping a future to Future[Unit]? myFuture.map(()) looks kinda ugly

Comment: While ugly, thats probably the best way to do it. You could do `.map(_ => ())` if you think its more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`Future[Unit]` would be better. You can use callback with your future as it returns unit. So, there will be success or failure.

```
futureResult.onComplete{
case Success(result) => //code
case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace
}
```